# Customize Rate module using Cpanel/Hostmonster

Tags: rating

I am using rate module(https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) for drupal 6, I want to use it in panels which is hostmonster but I dont know how, I have read the "readme.text" and it says I should put the php script somewhere in drupal.
Can you help me on how to do this, most of forums say the same, but some users like me are real newbies, I'd love to use the module, please help me on this, or perhaps you could write a step by step on how to do it.

Comment: After reading your question again, it is in fact not about this module is it? [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)

Answer (score 1):

The readme states you should enable the PHP input filter (The PHP module which is part of Drupal core). Then you can choose to use PHP code instead of Full- or Filterend HTML.
You should place the code there.

Also be aware that Drupal 6 is officially no longer supported and you are encouraged to update to Drupal 7 or Drupal 8. (See [On February 24th 2016, Drupal 6 will reach end of life and no longer be supported](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol).)

[image: PHP input filter]

From the [README](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rate/tree/README.txt):

```
8. Using rate in blocks or panels
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
You can place the rate widget on a node page in a block or (mini) panel. Add
a custom block with the PHP code input filter or a panel with PHP code and use
the following code:

<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && $node = node_load(arg(1))) {
  node_invoke_nodeapi($node, 'view');
  print $node->rate_NAME['#value'];
}
?>

Replace NAME by the widget's machine readable name.

The display setting for nodes must be set to "Do not add automatically".
```

Comment: Thank you for that information, I am thinking to upgrade my current version to drupal 7 in the near future, but as of this time I will be using this version to maintain the functionality of the website. So can I ask your help if you can walk me through the process of  building the right code to the rate module of my site? I have this site and I want it to be put here (https://www.hunnibunniboutique.co.uk/catalog/gifts-accessories/suitcases/hunnibunni-babes-personalised-beach-background-suitcase#.VyxryqodBBc) below the social media shares. May I know what is the code I should put?

Comment: The code that is in the [README](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rate/tree/README.txt) ;)

Comment: Yes I have the code already but when I put it here it will not function properly. Please see this  link "node-product.tpl.php" in dropbox. (https://www.dropbox.com/s/bvupbgi0zdv5azf/node-product.tpl.php?dl=0)

Comment: You asked how to do this in panels, so you should create a new panel field with this code and the PHP filter enabled. You should not be touching product.tpl.php

Comment: Do you know how to do that? Can you please help me?

Comment: Where should I go if I have to enable the PHP filter?

Comment: As I wrote on my first line, that is a module that ships with Drupal core.

Comment: And on your panel you add "New custom content" which is on the left. There you can type your code and choose to use the PHP filter.

Comment: Okay I will try working on it and will update you the status.Thank you

Comment: Sir this is what I've done. I never get the good result, it doesn't appear on my site. Can you please check it for me. I named the file "node-rate.tpl.php" under this cpanel: sites/all/themes/hunnibunni/templates (https://www.dropbox.com/s/qpjspkivrzhpqvt/node-rate.tpl.php?dl=0)

Comment: Maybe your name is not right, I cannot tell. README explains nothing about template files (yet you keep using them). I am not the module maintainer and do not know the inner workings. Perhaps create a support request in the module [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/rate?status=All).

Comment: okay i will write them. thank you so much for you help.